# Example of the dot operator yielding an rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

*C++ Primer (5th edition)* states that "*The dot operator yields an lvalue if the object from which the member is fetched is an lvalue; otherwise the result is an rvalue.*"

I'm trying to see an example where the dot operator yields an rvalue. For this to happen, the member fetched should be from an rvalue. How can an rvalue have a member? Can anyone show me an example of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cpp
struct RValue {
    int member;
};

RValue{}.member;
```

?

Comment: "Sadly", `struct {int x;}{}.x` isn't valid [tag:C++].  (But your answer is!)